# Performance in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

2 related questions :

---

**question #1 :**

I have a myTable with `id , name , lastname`

`id` is seed (pk).

`name` has index on it. //not nullAble.

which query is faster ?

- `select id , name , lastname from mytable where name = name  //(name has index on it!)`

or

- `select id , name , lastname from mytable`

---

**question #2 :** **now lets assume name is nullable.**

from the first sample

there is a select query sp which its parameter is `@name` + `@lastName`

(returning all rows where `name  = @name` or `lastName= @lastName`)

which query is faster ?

```
select id , name , lastname from mytable where 
   (@name is null or  name=@name)

and

   (@lastName is null or  lastName=@lastName)
```

> here if @name  or @lastName are null  - so it wont compare name=@name

or

```
 select id , name , lastname from mytable where 
       (name =  isNull(@name,name))

    and

      (lastName=  isNull(@lastName,lastName))
```

> here , if @name or @lastName are null , so there **STILL** will be equalization 
>   of  `name= name`  and `lastName=lastName` , which i think is bad
>   performance.

please help ?

Comment: Is `name` nullable? If so the queries in `question #1` aren't the same.

Comment: @MartinSmith no Its like that. I just think that if i added where which has index on it  - so it will be faster....no ?

Comment: I deleted my first comment that you just replied to and replaced it with another one...

Comment: @MartinSmith no not null able since null!=null . thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the first two queries are equivalent.

`name = name` will always evaluate true, and will be a constant evaluation basically.  Both of those queries will run a table scan.

The second two queries should be equivalent as well.

`ISNULL` may be slightly faster but I doubt it - the optimizer expands it out to a `CASE` statement so it will likely short circuit.

Comment: name = name  - will have to be evaluated each row... so I think its gonna heart performance... no?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No - it is not, If name IS NULL - then it will not return the row

Comment: @RoyiNamir `name = name` is a nonsense evaluation, equivalent to `1=1`.  It won't be checked for each row.

Comment: @jnk for the #2 answer - isnull is not faster then is null. ive checked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Both performs the same except if your table is **full of** NULL names, and only few names have a value - then 1st will perform faster due to less rows will return
2. the first looks better, since can be optimized by server if any of parameters is null